# Preencher LineChart(Gráfico de linhas) wpf com dados de uma consulta sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, chart

Olá, estou tendo problemas em encontrar uma solução para preencher meu linechart com dados de uma consulta, minha classe de conexão está completa e funcionando, mas não sei aplicar no chart, não sei como criar automaticamente, apenas insiro valores.

Atualmente meu gráfico é alimentado por dados inseridos através do code-behind:

[image: Exemplo]

Wpf:

```
        <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Series Demo" Margin="0,10,10,54">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" 

    IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 

    IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Código c#:

```
public partial class Charts : Window
{

    public Charts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showColumnChart();
    }

    private void showColumnChart()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("oculos", 60));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("lentes prontas", 200));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("manutenção", 10));
        lineChart.DataContext = valueList;
    }
}
```

tenho uma tabela com estes mesmos valores e gostaria de usar eles a partir da tabela no sql server, podendo adicionar ou remover depois sem alterar o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte, faça a extração dos dados da consulta do banco p/ uma ObservableCollection(você vai precisar ter a classe dessa consulta) ou um List. Depois você pode criar um foreach p/ percorrer e inserir no chart.

Comment: vou tentar agora e te aviso.

Comment: teria como enviar um código exemplo?